# Use java and xargs(?) to supply only arguments to java program and not replace stdin

Tags: java, xargs

I have a written a small java program that takes arguments from the commandline and should then be interactive.

When I want to test with large input I want to pipe the contents of a file to the JVM to use as the input arguments to the program but I don't want to replace stdin with the file contents.

So I tried

less file | xargs -0 java -cp ... mypackage.ClassName

but this replaces stdin with the file contents I think so the interactive portion of the program that uses BufferedReader.readLine() takes its content from the file instead.

Is there any way I can first pipe the contents of the file to the JVM then switch back to StdIn?

Im running Ubunthu

Code example:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String cmd;
while(true) {
    try {
    System.out.print(">");
    cmd = br.readLine(); //becomes null if I start the program as above
```

Ps. It would be better for the java program to work with files but I want to know if this is possible Ds.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Do you want `java -cp … --other-argument <contents-of-a-file> --another-argument mypackage.ClassName`? So you can parse the command line for that argument? Maybe you should give us a minimal code example from your Java program? What do you *really* need to achieve – i.e. what is in this file and why can't you just give your program the file path and let that open the file?

Comment: @slhck Instead of e.g. java -cp ... myclass "Argument0 Arugment1" I want to do: java myclass <contents of file>. After this I want the program to run and stdin in java take input from stdin

Comment: You can get the contents of a file evaluated in the command line like so: `java myclass "$(<some-file.txt)"` — but this is a really bad hack and you should modify your Java program to take a file name as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the scolding: One of the lesser-known rules of shell script programming (and even interactive shell use) is ***do not use***

> `cat` *some_file* `|` *some_command*

unless you have a very good reason to. 
Oh, sure, it works, but it’s inefficient and bad style.  And, sure,

> `cat` *some_file*

is the simplest way to display a file on the terminal; that’s fine.  And

> `cat` *options* *file* `|` *some_command*

and

> `cat` *file<sub>1</sub>* *file<sub>2</sub>* `|` *some_command*

are OK.  But

> `cat` *some_file* `|` *some_command*

(with only one filename on the `cat` command line) can almost always be converted to

> *some_command* **`<`** *some_file*

And I hope it goes without saying that, if

> `cat` *some_file* `|` *some_command*

is bad,

> `less` *some_file* `|` *some_command*

is probably worse.  Why don’t you say

> `xargs -0 java -cp ... mypackage.ClassName` **`<`** *file*

?  But that wouldn’t solve your problem.

---

I believe that

## the answer you’re looking for is:

> `xargs` **`–a`** *file*  `-0 java -cp ... mypackage.ClassName`

This (or, equivalently,**--arg-file=***file*) tells `xargs` to open *file*, ***not as standard input***, and read from it and process it the way it would normally handle stdin, but leave the original standard input alone, and make it available to the exec’ed program.  Warning: not all versions of `xargs` support this.

By the way, are you expecting *file* to be so big that its contents cannot fit on a command line, so your program will need to be exec’ed multiple times, with subsets of *file* as arguments?

Comment: I want to use it to supply large files as input.

Basically I made a bad implementation but then got a bit curious about how one can use (or abuse) these types of operations.

Comment: I was wondering because, if your file is large, then @slhck’s suggestion of `"$(<some-file.txt)"` probably wouldn’t have worked.